# SingleInstance of Android launchMode

Tags: android, launchmode

I read the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#ManifestForTasks) and understood that `singleInstance` is always opened by creating a new task. So I thought that if I run two activities with the same `taskAffinity`, only the last opened activity will be on the back stack. However, when two activities are opened as `singleInstance` with the same `taskAffinity`, both activities are stacked on the back stack. How do I understand `singleInstance`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is pretty easy: `taskAffinity` trumps `launchMode`. This means, if you launch an `Activity` and that `Activity` has the same `taskAffinity` as other activities within a task, the special `launchMode`s `singleTask` and `singleInstance` are ignored.

So unfortunately, the documentation isn't 100% correct, because there are some situations where `singleInstance` and `singleTask` launch modes do NOT behave the way they are documented.

In general, you should not be using the special launch modes `singleTask` or `singleInstance` as these come with a lot of side-effects that are not obvious. You shouldn't need these special launch modes unless you are implementing a HOME-screen replacement.